# UITableView header disappears under the UINavigationBar using a standard UITableViewController

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an `UITableViewController` inside an `UINavigationController`. I added a `UISearchBar` as the `tableView.header`:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.tableView.frame.size.width,44.0)];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

**The problem**: When scrolling the tableHeader disappears under the navigationBar.

I already tried to set the `navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO` but it seems this trick doesn't work using a standard UITableViewController.

Is there a way to fix this problem using a standard UITableViewController? I want it to works exactly as it does in Contacts app. I target iOS7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up using the `UITableViewController` and I solved using a standard `UIViewController` with a `UISearchBar` on top and a `UITableView` under it. By setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` the `UISearchBar` won't overlap the status bar when the search begins:

```
-(id) initWithTableViewStyle: (int) tableViewStyle
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        //Set the UITableViewStyle
        self.tableViewStyle = tableViewStyle;

        //Be sure the searchBar won't overlap the status bar
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        //Add the subviews to the mainView
        [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
        [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

        //Autolayout

        //Create the views dictionary
        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"searchBar":self.searchBar,
                                          @"tableView": self.tableView};

        //Create the constraints using the visual language format
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|[searchBar]|"
                                   options:0
                                   metrics:nil
                                   views:viewsDictionary]];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|[tableView]|"
                                   options:0
                                   metrics:nil
                                   views:viewsDictionary]];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[searchBar(==44)][tableView]|"
                                       options:0
                                       metrics:nil
                                       views:viewsDictionary]];
    }
    return self;

}

-(UITableView*) tableView
{
    if (!_tableView){

        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)
                                                  style:self.tableViewStyle];
        _tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource=self;
    }
    return _tableView;
}

-(UISearchBar*) searchBar
{
    if(!_searchBar){

        _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
        _searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        _searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        _searchBar.translucent = NO;
        _searchBar.delegate = self;
    }
    return _searchBar;
}
```

The UIViewController should be made:

```
UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,
                                          UISearchBarDelegate,
                                          UISearchDisplayDelegate,
                                          UITableViewDataSource,
                                          UITableViewDelegate>
```